# Any facts that users’ secret key is stolen on some group?

Tags: key-exchange

I am wondering whether some severe accidents due to sharing a secret key exist in real world.

A group of users or a company typically share a secret key to decrypt some shared encrypted data possibly stored on cloud storage.

However, each user has to be responsible for secret key management. I think not all of the users do that propery.
Is anyone aware of some severe accidenst where the shared secret key had been  stolen and all the entire data was stolen as well?

I am sorry if this topic is not related to this website.

Comment: I would expect many people to be aware of such incidents. And many who will not answer, for obvious reasons. In fact this is one of those occasions where you should expect better answers from search engines, as they will deliver public incidents.

Comment: Severe accidents due to shared primes in RSA moduli are known; see e.g. [smartfacts](https://smartfacts.cr.yp.to/index.html). Does that count at "sharing a secret key"? You decide.